# Name mangling in existing libs - conflict

Tags: c++, dll, name-mangling

We have a lot of compiled C++ tools including some statically linked C++ libraries. We had extended some libs and of course recompiled it -> now the newer dll's are not compatible with the older C++ tools!

error:

> TransceiveDataRaw@CCommonUtils@RegTestAPI@@QAEIPAEH0AAHPBD2@Z could
>   not be located in the dynamic link library IFX_CC_RegTestBase.dll

Is there any way to ignore this name mangling without recompiling our tools (there are hundreds of them)?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. Different C++ compilers (and sometimes different versions of the same compiler) use different name mangling schemes, and in a way this is a safety mechanism. Along with a name mangling system, there are runtime mechanisms unique to a given compiler, and these won't be compatible either: virtual method dispatch, for example. The fact that these won't link is probably saving you from building an executable that would just crash and burn.